# How to use the hidapi library from Signal11?

Tags: c, gcc, hidapi

I installed the hidapi library from Signall11 on my windows10 pc (using minGW). But now I'm having some trouble actually getting it to work with gcc. I have some main.c file in which I include the hidapi.h file. My gcc command looks like

```
gcc main.c
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong because whenever I try to run this command I get an undefined reference error to some function that is defined in the hidapi.h file.

Comment: is `hidapi` a library you need to be linking against but are only including the header?

Answer (score 1):

A full compile command for a project using hidapi is like this:

```
gcc -o your_app your_app.c -lhidapi-hidraw
```

It's not enough to include  `#include "hidapi.h"` in the C-code, which does let `gcc` compile. You also need `-lhidapi-hidraw` to link with the library. I.e. compiling is in fact a 2 step process.